# Oracle Reports - How to Capture Page Number and Insert to Database?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oraclereports

I have fields linked to page number and total page number. And that's pretty simple.(Image below)

[image]

But I also want to capture the page number in "BETWEEN PAGES " trigger and insert into database.(image below)

[image]

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Getting the current page number is trivial; use `SRW` built-in package, its `GET_PAGE_NUM` function. For example:

```
declare
  l_page_num number;
begin
  srw.get_page_num (l_page_num);

  insert into some_table (page_number) values (l_page_num);
end;
```